# HTML Layout/Templating

Tags: html, templates, layout, angularjs

I am building a website where i'm looking to create html templates which contain placeholders where i'll be able to inject pages/content, menus, etc.... I really like AngularJS which has  good support for this but am thinking that it might be a bit of an overkill for what i'm building. There is a chance some parts of the application will eventually be ripped out and run standalone and so dont want to tie the html/javascript to a library which requires so much framework specific syntax. Are there any other, simpler libraries, that will allow me to do this? thanks in advance

/Eric

Comment: Look into Underscore templates with Backbone, or Handlebars.js

Comment: Yeah, any kind of template engine would do the trick. Handlebars, Jade, Haml, or more static things like Jekyll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KnockoutJS is pretty lightweight and also includes a [templating](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) feature.

I wouldn't just dismiss angularjs because it seems like a heavy framework. There are very simple ways to use it without using any of the "advanced" features like routing, creating services, creating directives, etc. You can simply have a controller and use the built in directives to do a lot of powerful things on a single page. Angular is also pretty small and is easily bootstrapped with the ng-app tag anywhere in your DOM.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've been looking more att angularjs and as you say, i can probably skip some of the more advanced features to keep the learning easy for the rest of the team.